# Date format to utc month date and year (MMM DD, YYYY)

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

Hi I'm trying to change this date Mar 29, 2017 into a utc date:

This is what I tried:

```js
var isoDate = new Date('Mar 29, 2017').toISOString();

//isoDate => returns "2017-03-28T22:00:00.000Z"
```

Why am I getting 28T22 at the begginning instead of 29??

Comment: How is that output wrong? midnight, Mar 29, 2017 CET is 22:00 Mar 28, 2017 UTC (which is "2017-03-28T22:00:00.000Z" in ISO format)

Comment: See this [link](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/cet-to-utc-converter) for more info. - you see CET is +2h or from the other side UTC is -2h.

Comment: whats your timezone? ```toISOString()``` will show date by adding/subtracting time difference between UTC and your timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert in UTC timezone, not CET.

**CET** stands for *Central European Time*. 
**UTC** is known as *Universal Time*.

**UTC is 2 hours behind CET.**

So, when it is **11:00am CET** it will be **9am UTC**.

`toISOString()` will show date by adding/subtracting time difference between UTC and your timezone. (see comments)

Comment: Worth noting here is it's possible to create a date by UTC regardless of timezone, but it's a lot stricter with how it's done. To get `2017-03-29T00:00:00.000Z` one could do this: `new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 2, 29))`

Answer (score 3):

> Why am I getting 28T22 at the begginning instead of 29??

Well simply because you are forcing it, you are using `.toISOString()` which will return the date in ISO format.

Because `Mar 29, 2017 T00:00:00.000Z` in **CET** is `2017-03-28T22:00:00.000Z` in **ISO** format.

You can check **[the difference between UTC and CET time zones](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/cet-to-utc-converter)** for further details.